# Postman. "message": "Missing \"data\" payload in the request body",

Tags: requests, postman, strapi

пытаюсь отправить пост запрос с фотографией. Но совершенно не понимаю как это сделать. Пробовал через "binary" отправить - получаю ошибку как в заголовке.
Пробовал через form-data, получаю -

```
 "status": 500,
        "name": "InternalServerError",
        "message": "Internal Server Error"
```

PS: Ключ должен быть "foto"
PSS: Отправляю на сервер strapi. Разрешение выдал
[image: form-data]
[image: binary]

Comment: так а в запросе токена не должно быть никакого?

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin Нет, все запросы просто отправлял